# How to carry text from my edittext, from 1 activity to another and clear if empty

Tags: android

I have a problem with a task list/manager app I'm making. I have an EditText on my ViewTasksActivity with a button to go to AddTaskActivity I have it set up so that if text is entered into the ViewTasksActivity activity EditText, it will show it in the AddTaskActivity. This is good but it stores it in memory so if i enter new text on the ViewTasksActivity EditText it will actually add it to the end of what ever was written before and carry it to the AddTaskActivity! confusing! im sorry but i cant find the words to describe it!

here is the code i have so far...

public class ViewTasksActivity extends TaskManagerActivity {

```
private EditText taskNameEditText;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    taskNameEditText = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.EditText_taskName);
}

// Buttons Start
public void Button_chooseTaskList_Clicked(View view) {

}
public void Button_createNewTask_Clicked(View view) {
    String taskName = taskNameEditText.getText().toString();
    Task t = new Task(taskName);
    getTaskManagerApplication().addTask(t);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddTaskActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
// Buttons End
```

}

main.xml is

```
<TableLayout 
    android:id="@+id/Table_tableTop"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/Divider_1"
    android:paddingTop="5dip"
    android:paddingLeft="4dip"
    android:stretchColumns="2" >

    <TableRow>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button_chooseTaskList"
            android:background="@drawable/iv_newtask"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:onClick="Button_chooseTaskList_Clicked"
            />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditText_taskName"
            android:hint="@string/edittext_hint_text_name"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:textSize="13dip" 
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button_createNewTask"
            android:background="@drawable/button_addnewtask"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:onClick="Button_createNewTask_Clicked"
            />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

addtaskactivity is

```
public class AddTaskActivity extends TaskManagerActivity {

private EditText taskNameEditText;
private DateFormat fmtDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG);
private DateFormat fmtTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);
private TextView showDate;
private TextView showTime;
private TextView showEndDate;
private TextView showEndTime;
private Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_task);

    taskNameEditText = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.EditText_taskName);
    showDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showDate);
    showTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showTime);
    showEndDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showEndDate);
    showEndTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showEndTime);

    setupListSpinner();
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    showTaskName();
}

private void showTaskName() {
    ArrayList<Task> tasks = getTaskManagerApplication().getCurrentTasks();
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (Task t:tasks) {
        sb.append(String.format("%s", t.toString()));
    }
    taskNameEditText.setText(sb.toString());
}
```

add_task.xml is

```
<TableLayout 
        android:id="@+id/Table_taskName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/Divider_1"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:paddingLeft="4dip"
        android:paddingRight="4dip"
        android:stretchColumns="2" >

        <TableRow>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/EditText_taskName"
                android:hint="@string/edittext_hint_text_name"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:textSize="13dip" 
                />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
```

as I said, it holds the info but even when the app is closed it still holds it in memory. 
help please!!

Thanks
Kris

Answer (score 0):

Hi friend use this code to transfer your edit text value from one activity to another

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                                   bundle.putString("S2",edittext.getText().toString());

Intent i = new Intent(PageCommunicationActivity.this, NextActivity.class);

i.putExtras(bundle);

startActivity(i);

where "S2" is the key value and retrive the value from next activity by using below code

Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

s2=bundle.getString("S2");

Comment: thanks dude, much appreciated, and a lot easier than the way i done it!